# Is There a Faster Way to Pull a Text Snippet from CSV, Search Subfolders on a File Server, Rename Folder When Hit Occurs, and Move to Next Record?

Tags: powershell, performance, csv, directory

I have 100,000 records in a CSV to parse portions of Column3 for alphanumeric text before a series of characters that I split to grab said text, then use that to search a file server's subfolders four levels down and, if a match is made, rename that folder with some prepended text from Column1 in the CSV. The script below works well but is slow as hell and will likely take days to complete in its current form. Any gifted insights that might speed things up significantly so it will finish before my great-great-grandkids retire?

Thanks in advance.

```
$folderPath = "Z:\TopLevelFolder\*\*\*\*"
$csvPath = "C:\PathToCSV\file.csv"
$count = 0

$csvData = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath

foreach ($row in $csvData)
{
    $prefix = ($row.Column3 -split ' - ')[0]
    $prepend = ($row.Column1 -split '-')[-1]
    $subfolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    foreach ($subfolder in $subfolders)
    {
        if ($subfolder.Name -like "*$prefix*")
        {
            $newName = "("+ $prepend + ") " + $subfolder.Name
            Rename-Item -Path $subfolder.FullName -NewName $newName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            $count++
            Write-Host $subfolder.FullName
        }
    }
}
Write-Host $count.ToString() "folders renamed"
```

Comment: Yes, as a first step, you might consider to put the (static) `$subfolders = Get-ChildItem ...` command completely outside the outer loop (of `100.000` records).

Comment: For a next step, you might consider to filter your `$subfolders` and then [index](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations#looking-up-entries-by-property-in-large-collections) it by removing everything from the filename that is not an `$Prefix`.

Comment: Check Task Manager and see the memory usage.  If memory is high is could be reason for long time.  Also if you have links in your filesystem you could be in a loop.

Comment: Oh my deity, Ron, that one simple change (moving $subfolders out of the loop) sped things up exponentially. Holiest of holy craps... Thank you!